# how to parse this complex json in flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, rest

Help me to parse this complex json data..!!!

I'm getting an error like this
**type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'**

**This is my response**

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "user": 3,
            "memory": "I saw that you were perfect, and so I loved you. Then I saw that you were not perfect and I loved you even more.",
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "hashtag": "#trend"
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "hashtag": "#honeymoon"
                }
            ],
            "photos": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "photo": "http//IMG_1622365232437.png/"
                }
            ],
            "connections": [],
            "likes": [],
            "views": [],
            "date": "2021-05-24",
            "time": "02:00:00",
            "created_at": "2021-05-30T09:00:35.172231Z",
            "fontfamily": "Pacifico",
            "is_liked": false,
            "is_bookmarked": false,
            "is_archived": false
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "user": 3,
            "memory": "I saw that you were perfect, and so I loved you. Then I saw that you were not perfect and I loved you even more.",
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "hashtag": "#love"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "hashtag": "#relationship"
                }
            ],
            "photos": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "photo": "http://api/v1/user-media/posts/sample_aBlr8us.jpg/"
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "photo": "http://api/v1/user-media/posts/hannah-grace-9W-vKFq4oEM-unsplash_ngXrYYP.jpg/"
                }
            ],
            "connections": [],
            "likes": [],
            "views": [],
            "date": "2021-05-26",
            "time": "16:35:00",
            "created_at": "2021-05-30T09:03:00.122267Z",
            "fontfamily": "Roboto",
            "is_liked": false,
            "is_bookmarked": false,
            "is_archived": false
        }
    ]
}
```

**My model code**

```
class UserPosts {
  int count;
  String next;
  String previous;
  List<Results> results;

  UserPosts({this.count, 
  this.next, this.previous,
   this.results
  });

  factory UserPosts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserPosts(
      count: json['count'],
      next: json['next'],
      previous: json['previous'],
      results: parseResults(json),
    );
  }

  static List<Results> parseResults(resultsJson) {
    var list = resultsJson['results'] as List;
    List<Results> resultsList =
        list.map((data) => Results.fromJson(data)).toList();
    return resultsList;
  }
}

class Results {
  int id;
  int user;
  String memory;
  List<HashTags> hashtags;
  List<Photos> photos;
  List<String> connections;
  List<String> likes;
  List<String> views;
  String date;
  String time;
  String fontfamily;
  bool is_liked;
  bool is_bookmarked;
  bool is_archived;

  Results(
      {this.id,
      this.user,
      this.memory,
      this.hashtags,
      this.photos,
      this.connections,
      this.likes,
      this.views,
      this.date,
      this.time,
      this.fontfamily,
      this.is_liked,
      this.is_bookmarked,
      this.is_archived
      });

  factory Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var connectionsFromJson = json['connections'];
    List<String> connectionsList = connectionsFromJson.cast<String>();
    var likesFromJson = json['likes'];
    List<String> likesList = likesFromJson.cast<String>();
    var viewsFromJson = json['views'];
    List<String> viewsList = viewsFromJson.cast<String>();
    return new Results(
        id: json['id'] as int,
        user: json['user'],
        memory: json['memory'],
        hashtags: parseHashTags(json),
        photos: parseImages(json),
        connections: connectionsList,
        likes: likesList,
        views: viewsList,
        date: json['date'],
        time: json['time'],
        fontfamily: json['fontfamily'],
        is_liked: json['is_liked'],
        is_bookmarked: json['is_bookmarked'],
        is_archived: json['is_archived']);
  }

  static List<HashTags> parseHashTags(hashTagsJson) {
    var list = hashTagsJson['hashtags'] as List;
    List<HashTags> hashtagsList =
        list.map((data) => HashTags.fromJson(data)).toList();
    return hashtagsList;
  }

  static List<Photos> parseImages(imagesJson) {
    var list = imagesJson['photos'] as List;
    List<Photos> imagesList =
        list.map((data) => Photos.fromJson(data)).toList();
    return imagesList;
  }
}

class HashTags {
  int id;
  String hashtag;

  HashTags({this.id, this.hashtag});

  factory HashTags.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new HashTags(id: json['id'] as int, hashtag: json['hashtag']);
  }
}

class Photos {
  int id;
  String photo;

  Photos({this.id, this.photo});

  factory Photos.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Photos(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      photo: json['photo']
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my fetch code. But I got an error like this "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

```
  List<UserPosts> list = [];

  Future fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    print("YES");

    try {
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
      };
      // final jsonEndpoint = Uri.parse("http://api/v1/posts/");
      final jsonEndpoint = Uri.parse("$baseurl/user-memory/");
      final response = await http.get(jsonEndpoint, headers: headers);
      print(response.body);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          for (Map i in data) {
            list.add(UserPosts.fromJson(i));
          }
          loading = false;
        });
      } else {
        print("failed");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This's reason for bug  `var list = resultsJson['results'] as List;`  it's not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

Example below code:

```
static List<Results> parseResults(resultsJson) {
    var list = List<Results>();
    resultsJson['results'].forEach((v) {
        list.add(Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    return list;
  }
```